# How to avoid extra inputs request in OpenApi & Java?

Tags: java, spring, api, swagger, openapi

Is it possible to have a validation to avoid sending any extra parameters on the requests?

For example, in my endpoint, the consumer should send these parameters: `name`, `family`, `email`

I want to avoid the consumer by sending any extra, such as: `name`, `family`, `email`, **`phone`**.

I'm using the following way to handle endpoints:

OpenApi Swagger Spec:

```yaml
post:
  tags:
    - '/user'
  operationId: saveUser
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        schema:
          type: object
             properties:
                name:
                   type: string
                family:
                   type: string
                email:
                   type: string
```

Java:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
default ResponseEntity<Void> postUser(
    @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
    @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestParam(value = "family", required = true) String family,
    @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestParam(value = "email", required = true) String email
) {
    return getDelegate().saveUser(name, family, email);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I understand the problem, is the consumer sending more data fields? and is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, for some reason, I need to force the consumers to send only what I defined in the endpoint. @MartinByers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a solution for your problem. I think that every API developer would be more then happy if he could restrict incorrect content sent by the user.
What you could do is to check the content in your java method the content and return a corrosponding HTTP Code to indicate the error. You can add the statuscodes directly in your YAML OpenAPI like this:

```
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Correct Request, all Parameters are correct
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestSuccessful'
    "400":
      description: Bad input, some parameters are wrong or missing
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestError'
```